# How to replace inner array in php?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have one array as follows :

```
    Array
    (
        [154541] => Array
            (
                **[3831211] => Array
                    (
                        [34443] => 34443
                        [34444] => 34444
                        [34438] => 34438
                        [34442] => 34442
                        [34450] => 34450
                    )**

            )

        [154514] => Array
            (
                **[3830597] => Array
                    (
                        [34442] => 34442
                        [34450] => 34450
                        [34443] => 34443
                        [34444] => 34444
                        [34438] => 34438
                    )**

            )

        [154477] => Array
            (
                **[3829564] => Array
                    (
                        [34442] => 34442
                        [34444] => 34444
                        [34438] => 34438
                        [34450] => 34450
                        [34443] => 34443
                    )**

                [3830046] => Array
                    (
                        [34442] => 34442
                        [34444] => 34444
                        [34443] => 34443
                        [34438] => 34438
                        [34450] => 34450
                    )

            )

        [154474] => Array
            (
                [3829402] => Array
                    (
                        [34442] => 34442
                        [34450] => 34450
                        [34443] => 34443
                        [34438] => 34438
                        [34444] => 34444
                    )

            )

        [154472] => Array
            (
                [3831553] => Array
                    (
                        [34443] => 34443
                        [34450] => 34450
                        [34438] => 34438
                        [34444] => 34444
                        [34442] => 34442
                    )

                [3829803] => Array
                    (
                        [34443] => 34443
                        [34444] => 34444
                        [34450] => 34450
                        [34442] => 34442
                        [34438] => 34438
                    )

                [3829802] => Array
                    (
                        [34443] => 34443
                        [34444] => 34444
                        [34438] => 34438
                        [34450] => 34450
                        [34442] => 34442
                    )

                [3831552] => Array
                    (
                        [34444] => 34444
                        [34450] => 34450
                        [34443] => 34443
                        [34442] => 34442
                        [34438] => 34438
                    )

                [3830078] => Array
                    (
                        [34444] => 34444
                        [34442] => 34442
                        [34443] => 34443
                        [34438] => 34438
                        [34450] => 34450
                    )

            )
)
```

Now I want to replace the inner array(I have made that inner array as ** in above array) with my new generated array called $alerts.

I am not getting how to replace that inner-array with $alerts array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
$array[154541] = array("3831211" => $alerts);
```

or if the inner array has more elements:

```
$array[154541][3831211] = $newData;
```

Comment: I want to replace whole 3rd inner array.Not any single element.

Comment: Yes so what is the problem with that?